# Variable "date" is accessed from within inner class, need to be declared as final

Tags: android, android-studio

im getting an error saying 
"variable "date" is accessed within inner class, need to declared as final"

i have declared as final didn't work

```
final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    EditText etxt_currentmilage,etxt_liters,etxt_amount,etxt_totcost,etxt_date;
    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fuelup, container, false);
        final EditText etxt_date = rootView.findViewById(R.id.etxt_date);

        /*String currentdate = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(calendar.getTime());*/

       final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                                  int dayOfMonth) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                updateLabel();
            }

        };

        etxt_date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                new DatePickerDialog(FuelUp.this, date, calendar
                        .get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    private void updateLabel(){
        String myFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"; //In which you need put here
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);

        etxt_date.setText(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
    }

}
```

Comment: on which line do you get this error?

Comment: new DatePickerDialog(FuelUp.this, date, calendar

Comment: try rebuilding, or roll-back your changes, and use the Android Studio's hint to fix it. Set cursor on the red-underlined code, press alt+Enter, and select the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the following for to pick your date...hope this helps

```
etxt_date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(AddCarActivity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

                        month++;

                        String newMonth = month + "", newDay = dayOfMonth + "";

                        if (month < 10) {
                            newMonth = "0" + month;
                        }
                        if (dayOfMonth < 10) {
                            newDay = "0" + dayOfMonth;
                        }
                        String finalDate = year + "-" + newMonth + "-" + newDay;
                        dateTV.setText(finalDate);
//do anything you want with the date
                    }
                }, newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

                datePickerDialog.show();
            }
        });
```

and this

```
Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialize date object outside the onCreateView Method.